# How to typecast shorthand on declaration

Tags: typescript

I have a list of a generic type `MatcherNode`.

I want to cast the items to specific types, is there some shorthand for this?

The below code doesn't work.

```
type PlyMatcherNode = { tpe: "ply" }
type SanMatcherNode = { tpe: "san" }
type MatcherNode = PlyMatcherNode | 
                   SanMatcherNode | 
                   {  tpe: "other" }

function twoPlyMoveReducer
  (nodes: Array<MatcherNode>): MatcherNode {
    let [ply0: PlyMatcherNode, 
         san0: SanMatcherNode, 
         san1: SanMatcherNode] = nodes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the argument as a tuple type instead:

```
function twoPlyMoveReducer
  (nodes: [PlyMatcherNode, SanMatcherNode, SanMatcherNode]): MatcherNode {
    const [ply0, san0, san1] = nodes;
```

[TypeScript demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNiAsgQ2AYwBYQE4DkD2AJtALxQDeUwkAXFAERgL1QC+AUKJFAMrIB2KdFjxFSFKrQYBnASw5doQzDgLEoZeElQrR6gD5R2UE6bPmzfQTpFroh4xafnKkiHXr5gI+e3YAzAFd+NGAAS3x+KgB3fC1EfAA3CAAlCEJAtBxHAAp+MWk6AG14m1UxABpeAWVbSurrYXLiAF0ASigAegAqKDpa5uhuzopHEzRI6WAoIqYQAAYq2X5FqGWARhaNKHziaQBuP1YgA)

That said, from a code organization perspective, it seems *little bit* off to have mixed types like that in a single array. Consider if it would be feasible to refactor into, say, an array or single argument of `PlyMatcherNode`, and separately, an array argument of `SanMatcherNode` - I think it'd make more sense.

Comment: the reducer function is passed around with a specific signature, I thought to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the provided answer, I found a solution, that doesn't require to change the function signature:

```
function twoPlyMoveReducer(nodes: Array<MatcherNode> ): MatcherNode {
  let [ply0, san0, san1] = nodes as [PlyMatcherNode, 
                                     SanMatcherNode,
                                     SanMatcherNode];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be use a literal type in here?

```
type matcherNode = {tpe: "play"|"san"|"other"}

function twoPlyMoveReducer
  (nodes: matcherNode[]) /* : MatcherNode */ {
    const [ply0, san0, san1] = nodes;
    console.log(ply0)

}

twoPlyMoveReducer([{tpe:"play"},{tpe:"san"},{tpe:'other'}])
```